# How can I implement the AWS S3 put operation in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to modify the following PHP code – from a `copy_from` to a `put` – in order to transfer files from one S3 bucket to another in AWS. Tried a few variations but nothing works;

```
move_source = {"Bucket": bucket, "Key": filename}

var_tgt_obj = s3.ObjectSummary(dest_bucket.name, path + filename)
var_tgt_obj.copy_from(CopySource=move_source, SSEKMSKeyId=kms_key_id,ServerSideEncryption="aws:kms")
```

Comment: Please describe the behavior that makes you think that "nothing works". Does it give you an error or something?

Comment: The AWS SDKs are [very well documented](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/).

Comment: I don't know what language that that is, but it is certainly not PHP. You've also tagged boto3, which is a python library.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 PHP code examples are located in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). The Code Library should be the place to locate AWS Service API code examples in supported SDKs.

You can find PHP code examples for S3 here.

[Amazon S3 examples using SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/php_3_s3_code_examples.html)

As you are interested in copying an object to another bucket, look at this example:

[image]